# What thread does MTLCcommandBuffer.commit() operate on?

Tags: ios, swift, graphics, metal

Using metal, I'm working on drawing YUV420 images.

One problem is, when MTLCcommandBuffer.commit(), gesture actions such as Pinch or Pan slow down.

On which thread does commit() operate internally?
I wonder if it works on the main thread or on a separate thread.

If it works on the main thread, is there a way to operate it on a separate thread?

```swift
@objc func pinchAction(_ sender: UIPinchGestureRecognizer) {
    // this method called slowly
}

let commandBuffer: MTLCommandBuffer = (commandQueue?.makeCommandBuffer())!

func draw(in view: MTKView) {
    // do something...

    commandBuffer.present(view.currentDrawable!)
    commandBuffer.commit()
}
```

Comment: How have you determined that the call to `commit()` is the problem? Are you doing a time profile in Instruments or something else?

Comment: If do not do Commit(), the PinchAction will operate at normal speed.

Comment: Most probably it's not the `commit` that's slowing down, but the work done on the GPU that you just committed.

Comment: Then, if GPU performance is low, is it inevitable that PinchAction will slow down?

Comment: Yes, but there are ways to improve GPU performance. Why don't you post what your GPU drawing code does and we can look into improving that.